# Getting below error in flow’s update element when everything is correct

Tags: visual-workflow

This is the error I am getting when opening the update element. However, the flow is working fine.

```
"We can't reference fields. Check that they're still valid references and that you have permission to access them. For help, contact Salesforce Customer Support. Error ID: -191673043"
```

Record Triggered Flow is on my Client object ( custom obj ) which is lookup to cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the error id that you mentioned, your issue could be related one of the Known Issues from Salesforce. In this, when opening an update record element(which is on Custom Object), configured to update related records (of Standard object), an error pop up is thrown.

You can refer to the below KI link and see if the scenario matches your flow. If yes, please note that though the error is popping up, the flow will run as expected. To make any changes to the Update record component, you can delete and re-create the component.

KI Link > https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000j5k8EAAQ/error-on-opening-update-records-element-which-is-configured-on-custom-object-with-lookup-relationship-to-standard-object

I hope the above information helps.

Comment: Yes, the steps in the link looks like I am getting this because of the bug you mentioned. Thanks!